# How to use Google's "SimpleMinCostFlow" - C#

Tags: c#, optimization, using, max-flow

I want to create a Max Flow - Min Cost program in C# -Visual studio. I'm using this [Guide](https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/mincostflow) , but I get error at this line

`MinCostFlow minCostFlow = new MinCostFlow();` I'm sure I have to add a library at the `using` part

(near those: `using System.Windows.Forms;)` ,but I can't find the name of what library I should add. Do I need to install an special google package?

As the guide specifies, I need the following functions to work.

SimpleMinCostFlow methods:

```
AddArcWithCapacityAndUnitCost()
SetNodeSupply()
Head()
NumArcs()
NumNodes()
MaximumFlow()
OptimalCost()
Solve()
SolveMaxFlowWithMinCost()
Tail()
```

PS: [Here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/graph/min_cost_flow/SimpleMinCostFlow/) is some more info about the functions (those are C++, but should provide useful info). Found this new info about [StarGraph](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/graph/min_cost_flow/MinCostFlow/) maybe it helps.

As user Milos Mrdovic specifies, I added `using Google.OrTools.Graph;`, but it seems I am "missing an using directive or assembly reference" as you can see in the following picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJlSr.jpg)

Thank you,

Vlad

Comment: It looks like you are missing the following directive: using Google.OrTools.Graph; Also, you need to make sure the appropriate library is referenced in your project: execute "Install-Package Google.OrTools" in your package manager console.

Comment: I appreciate you took time to look over the question ! I will try this right away and come back with the feedback.

Comment: I installed the package and the problem has been solved, thank you Mr. Milos !

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED !
Go to `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console` and type "`Install-Package Google.OrTools`", hit enter. Credit to @Milos Mrdovic